# Нужно вывести 20 случайных чисел из диапазона 27 - 73 java

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Нужно вывести 20 случайных чисел из диапазона 27 - 73, перед каждым значением, делящимся на 3 без остатка, следует вывести (вплотную к числу) символ "#" (решетка).

```
public static void main(String[] args){        
        int y;        
        Random r = new Random();        
        for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++){        
            y = r.nextInt(27) + 47;        
            if (y % 3 = 0){        
                System.out.println("#" + y + " ");        
            } else {        
                System.out.println(y + " ");        
            }        
        }        
    }
```

У меня выдает ошибку:

> Error:(10, 19) java: unexpected type   required: variable   found:
>   value

Comment: Поздравляю, классическая ошибка ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (y % 3 = 0){
```

Нужно

```
if (y % 3 == 0){
```

Comment: Что то я тупой, спасибо)

Answer (score -2):

Ошибка в том , что ты объявил переменную (int y ) сразу после main функции , а потом объявляешь в блоке цикла еще переменную ( у ) , но джава не позволяет такого делать

В блоке цикла for у тебя динамическая инициализация  переменной ( у ) значения y = r.nextInt(27) + 47, но в main у тебя  тебя уже была объявлена переменная (у ) с пустым значением (ничего) int y

Советую в main убрать int y 
А в блоке кода for написать int y = r.nextInt(27) + 47;

Comment: Оооо, вам необходимо еще раз перечитать главу объявления переменных в `Java` )) У него там все в порядке, ошибка в условии...